# CRM 2011 Plugin not activated on Data Import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The plugin in question works just fine when using the CRM web front end.

However, when I am doing a data import from a previously exported and edited xml file, the plugin seems to be ignored.  I have tried registering the steps as both synchronous and asynchronous but I cannot get the plugin to be triggered when I do a Data Import.

It is not a problem with context.Depth, the plugin is never called at all so it doesn't even get to check the context.Depth.

Is there some server setting or some other reason why a plugin would simply be ignored when doing a data import?

**Edit**

Should mention that the plugin is currently deployed to disk (for debugging) if that affects anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing, it appears that the disk deployment was the problem.  For some reason CRM 2011 totally ignores your plugins during a Data-Import if they are deployed to disk.  After a long process of:

1) http://nicknow.net/dynamics-crm-ilmerge-dll-plugin/

2) http://nishantrana.me/2014/08/15/the-specified-type-is-not-a-known-entity-type-error-while-using-early-bound-entity-classes-in-crm-2013/

3) To figure out the minimum assemblies needed to make the early bound plugin work: [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

I finally have my plugin being activated during an import.